# Redshift: can't parse multiple items from list in JSON to each row

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a JSON in the RedShift.

"value" is stored in the inputs column as JSON text. Create a unique record for each "value". Look at the example below this table:

```
{"inputs": [{"name": "ambient", "desc": "Select from below the ambient setting that best decribe your environment right now", "values": ["Indoor - Loud", "Indoor - Normal", "Indoor - Whisper", "Outdoor - Loud", "Outdoor - Normal", "Outdoor - Whisper", "Semi-Outdoor - Loud", "Semi-Outdoor - Normal", "Semi-Outdoor - Whisper"]}
```

As a result it must be like this:
ProjectId : 10. Input value = Indoor – Loud
ProjectId : 10. Input value = Indoor – Normal
ProjectId : 10. Input value Indoor – Whisper

Each value need to be stored as one row in the dim_collect_user_inp_configs table. Example, Indoor-Loud as one row and it will have it’s own unique identifier as prompt_input_value_id, Indoor-Normal as one row and it will have it’s own unique identifier as prompt_input_value_id till the Semi-Outdoor-Whisper.

There could be multiple input “name” in one inputs column. Each name and its value need to be stored separately. Example :

```
[{"desc": "How many people does the video contain?", "name": "Number of People", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Only 1", "2-3", "3+"]}, {"desc": "What is the camera position?", "name": "Movement", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Fixed position", "Moving"]}, {"desc": "From which angle did you shoot the video?", "name": "Shoot Angle", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Frontal recording", "Tight angle: 10-40 degree", "Wide angle: 40-70 degree"]}, {"desc": "From which distance did you shoot the video?", "name": "Distance", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Near/Selfie", "Mid (3-6 ft)", "Far (>6 ft)"]}, {"desc": "What is the video lighting direction?", "name": "Lighting Direction", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Front lit", "Side lit", "Back lit"]}, {"desc": "What is the video background?", "name": "Background", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Outdoors", "In office", "At home", "Plain background"]}, {"desc": "What is the topic in your speech?", "name": "Topic", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Arts and Media", "Business", "Education", "Entertainment", "Food/Eating", "Nutrition", "Healthcare ", "High School Life", "Mental Health", "News", "Technology", "Morals and Ethics", "Phones and Apps", "Sports", "Science"]}]
```

I try to do it with this query:

```
WITH all_values AS (
        SELECT projectid AS projectid,
               prompttype AS prompttype,
               json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(inputs, 0, True), 'name') AS name,
               json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(inputs, 0, True), 'desc') AS description,
               json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(inputs, 0, True), 'values') AS value,
               scriptid AS scriptid,
               corpuscode AS corpuscode
        FROM source.table
        WHERE
            prompttype = 'input'
        GROUP BY projectid, prompttype, name, description, scriptid, corpuscode, value
        LIMIT 10
       )
SELECT * FROM all_values;
```

But now I haven't each row for "value" as I need. :(

Can you help me?

Thnx.

Comment: Postgres or Redshift? Please don't add tags for DBMS products not involved

Comment: I edited your question for you to remove reference and tags to postgres. its is completely different especially when looking at json.

Comment: Try creating a table from your json where the json is held in a SUPER type column. from there you have a lot more options to achieve what you want.

Comment: Well, yes, amazon-redshift was a fork of Postgres. But that was [Postgres 8.0.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Redshift) which reached [EOL](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/postgresql) in October 2010. They cannot (well at least should not) be considered similar anymore.